# Source of quote ~"so dumb they couldn't integrate e to the x..."

Tags: story-identification

"...well maybe x e to the x"

I have a vague memory of a title something like: Tavern at the end of the world.

Probably from 70-80's?

My DuckDuckGo search wasn't productive.

Comment: Maybe one of the *Callahan's Saloon* stories? That sounds like the kind of insult they might fire off.

Comment: yes Callahan's Saloon sounds likely, I'll look for it

Comment: Just in case someone forgot: the integral of "e to the x" is "e to the x" (plus a constant)

Comment: This reminds me of old engineering schools’ cheer: “E to the x, dy-dx. E to the x, dx. Secant, tangent, cosine, sine.  3.14159. Cube root, square root, BTU. Compass, slide rule! Go [PuuurDUE / Rice U / Duke U / T(ulane)U]!”

Comment: @WoJ and for "maybe _xeˣ_", integration by parts yields _(x-1)eˣ_ (+C of course)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The line appears in "[Silence Please](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56746)", a short story by Arthur C. Clarke that appears in "[Tales from the White Hart](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?31065)", the White Hart being a London pub where, like Callahan's saloon, tall tales were told.

The story concerns the invention of "Fenton's Silencer". Fenton is described as:

> Well, Rupert Fenton was one of our lab assistants. A very bright
> youngster, with a good mechanical background, but, naturally, not very
> well up in theory... But no-one expected he'd ever get very far,
> because I don't suppose he could even integrate e to the x."
>
> "Is such ignorance possible?" gasped someone.
>
> "Maybe I exaggerate. Let's say x e to the x. Anyway, all his knowledge
> was entirely practical—rule of thumb, you know.